# How long does it take for villagers to breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built an underground iron golem farm (making sure every door in the village has one block to the outside that is lit by the sunlight), and have cured 2 zombie villagers. I've put them in the chamber and awaited.

I'm at the tenth day (2 hour and 30 minutes+) since they began showing hearts on their head and they still haven't bred.

**Q:** What's the minimum and maximum required time for them to breed (assuming 48 doors/houses are provided)? Is there anyway to speed the process up?

I've tried taking a brief look at the [villager minecraft wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager) but I couldn't find any information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 0 seconds and +∞ seconds, respectively.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Are those ranges inclusive, or exclusive?

Comment: Heh, @IQAndreas, infinity can't be inclusive, and this zero isn't exact as well, because it takes some time for one iteration of the event loop to execute.

Comment: That's a bit extreme in my experience.  Are they adjacent to each other?  Are they able to move around?  I've had individual villagers caged so there is one block separating them, and they have not breeded, although they have displayed hearts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If villagers are emitting hearts, then you've done all you could for them. Now it is only a matter of them entering love mode simultaneously, which is entirely in the hands of God of Random.

I've been frustrated with my villagers not mating once, too. You can't do anything, regrettably. Just ensure your villagers can meet easily once they want to and wait - possibly find yourself something to do nearby.

Comment: "God of Pseudo Random", FTFY ;)

Comment: @Jefffrey considering that neither the seed for in-game events nor order of invocation is controllable, it is truly random for a playing observer :-)

Answer (score -3):

I play Xbox; and with the TU14 (title update 14), they added ender chests to Xbox and PS3

Now in this play session I was farming zombie pigs so it was set to "hard" so max spawn rate was achieved to farm for gold (for rail way I started and actually got the 1 villager I needed over from another village) any way the population is only 3, and its been that for a while now. Now don't say its from lack of houses:

- I've seen them  emit hearts
- There's been about 7 before

Comment: Hello, and welcome to gaming.se. While we appreciate your intent to contribute positively to the site, this particular question already had an accepted answer that was significantly better phrased. Please try your hand at questions that haven't been answered yet.